# (jQuery) Stop function when condition happens

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery structure like this:

```
$('#telefone').keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    console.log('backspace')
    return -1;
  }
}).on("input", function () {
   stuff();
}
```

I need it like this, because if i just do stuff() on `keyup`, some problems appear, while doing it using `.on` does exactly what it should. The thing is, if the user presses 'backspace', i want the function to stop, i don't want to do stuff(). The first block captures if the user is pressing backspace, and it works greatly, but how would i stop `on` from running?

I have also tried to do something like:

```
$('#telefone').on("input", function () {
    $('html').keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        console.log('backspace')
        return -1;
      }
    })
  stuff()
}
```

But it does not work either. The function can capture when backspace is pressed, but the `return` does not stop the `on` function. What should i do?

Comment: `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` is used to cancel event processing on the same element

Comment: So basically you want to... Prevent user hitting backspace on the keyboard, but allow every other possible events?

Comment: **What if** the user uses the keyboard arrows to move the caret in your input field and starts to write mid-text? This is an XY problem. Explain rather what are you trying to achieve, because I can only assume you're doing it wrong and you'll only get incomplete or problem-inaccurate answers. So the part *`"some problems appear"`* is actually the most important I think.

Comment: James Long's solution worked. That is beacuse there is another function that is supposed to run when the user presses backspace. That second function was running alongside this one, that should not run when backspace is pressed. It is now working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a flag of some kind

```
var isRunning = true;
$('#telefone').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}).on("input", function () {
    if (isRunning) {
        stuff();
    }
});
```

If you need to re-activate `stuff()` when the user has finished pressing the key, use the `keydown` event instead.

```
var isRunning = true;
$('#telefone').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}).keyup(function (e) {
    isRunning = true;
}).on("input", function () {
    if (isRunning) {
        stuff();
    }
});
```

Just as an aside, you can doo all of that in a single `.on()` call.

```
var isRunning = true;
$('#telefone').on({
    keydown: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    },
    keyup: function (e) {
        isRunning = true;
    },
    input: function () {
        if (isRunning) {
            stuff();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: since user input events aren't always handled synchronously...could there occasionally be unpredictable behavior with something like this?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I've never known it be an issue, but the body of the `keyup` function can be wrapped in something like `window.requestAnimationFrame` to delay re-activating the flag if it's an issue